# DOM Re-attaching IFrames on scroll event

Tags: angular

I am encountering a weird issue with DOM re-rendering when I scroll down.  I have a bunch of OEmbed data that needs to be rendered on the page, but can't seem to render it without it reloading all the embeded content on scroll.

https://plnkr.co/edit/qklbNzvDSOzoI2t0K7fA?p=preview

I have something like this right now:

```
<div class="content embed" *ngIf="item.template == 'embed'">
  <span [innerHTML]="trustHtml(item.embed.html)"></span>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to prevent the re-rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was because I was running a trustHtml inside of the loop.  I abstracted that to the API response layer and it works like a charm now.  So instead of:

```
<div class="content embed" *ngIf="item.template == 'embed'">
  <span [innerHTML]="trustHtml(item.embed.html)"></span>
</div>
```

I am doing:

```
<div class="content embed" *ngIf="item.template == 'embed'">
  <span [innerHTML]="item.embed.html"></span>
</div>
```

And then in my API response layer (before results get passed to component through an observer) I have:

```
item['html'] = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(item['html']);
```